# How i can know if an app which is added to a site is an Add-In or SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx

I am working on a site for a client, and i found this app added to the site;-

[image]

so how i can know if this app is an SPfx or it is Add-in?

Thanks